# VMWare Workstation screwed up wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, vmware-workstation

No idea what the hell went on, but after installing VMWare Workstation my wireless is kind of ruined. Connecting the laptop with an ethernet cord seems to fix the problem, but even when I'm not running any virtual machines.

Comment: Would you like to elaborate on what exactly is happening, and what "being kind of ruined" involves?

Comment: Ah, should have said. My download speed isn't anything greater than a 128k line, however my upload is just fine. Ping? A-okay.

Comment: VMWare creates a couple of network Interfaces on the host. Perhaps you could try disabling them explicitly and then checking if the symptoms persist.

Comment: Have you tried un-installing VMWare to see if the problem clears up?  I'd do that first, *then* try to troubleshoot whichever scenario (installed or not) remains problematic.

Comment: Hi! I have exactly the same problem, do you remember how did you fix it? I have a VMware Workstation 10